# Remove keys from array in django rest framework serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Consider this json response from one of my endpoint in a django rest framework web app.

```
{
"links": {
    "next": null,
    "previous": null
},
"count": 2,
"total_pages": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "movie": {
            "id": 13,
            "title": "Living Doll",
            "genres": [
                {
                    "genre": "Horror"
                }
            ],
            "imdbID": "tt0100038",
            "poster": "/8VUR5PN3yqRoK9M65BASDrZ4Imd.jpg",
            "language": "en",
            "favourite": false,
            "watch_later": true,
            "watched": false
        }
    },
    {
        "movie": {
            "id": 230,
            "title": "Porno",
            "genres": [
                {
                    "genre": "Romance"
                },
                {
                    "genre": "Comedy"
                }
            ],
            "imdbID": "tt0100388",
            "poster": "/dNkLerizbd53flidKiippvBTns4.jpg",
            "language": "pl",
            "favourite": true,
            "watch_later": true,
            "watched": false
        }
    }
]
```

}

See the redundant movie key in each elements in the array. How do I remove them to make it like this?

```
{
"links": {
    "next": null,
    "previous": null
},
"count": 2,
"total_pages": 1,
"results": [
        {
            "id": 13,
            "title": "Living Doll",
            "genres": [
                "Horror"
            ],
            "imdbID": "tt0100038",
            "poster": "/8VUR5PN3yqRoK9M65BASDrZ4Imd.jpg",
            "language": "en",
            "favourite": false,
            "watch_later": true,
            "watched": false
        },
       {
            "id": 230,
            "title": "Porno",
            "genres": [
                   "Romance",
                   "Comedy"
            ],
            "imdbID": "tt0100388",
            "poster": "/dNkLerizbd53flidKiippvBTns4.jpg",
            "language": "pl",
            "favourite": true,
            "watch_later": true,
            "watched": false
        }

]
```

}

Also see the genres. They need to be like the second json without the keys.

The serializer for the aboove json response is given below

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    genres = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    favourite = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    watch_later = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    watched = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('id','title','genres','imdbID','poster','language','favourite','watch_later','watched')
        read_only_fields =('title','genres','imdbID' ,'poster','language')

    def get_genres(self, obj):
        qs = MovieGenre.objects.filter(movie=obj)
        return GenreSerializer(qs,many=True).data

    def get_favourite(self, obj):
        result = UserList.objects.filter(user=self.context.get('request').user,movie=obj)
        if result:
            return result[0].favourite
        return False

    def get_watch_later(self, obj):
        result = UserList.objects.filter(user=self.context.get('request').user,movie=obj)
        if result:
            return result[0].watch_later
        return False

    def get_watched(self, obj):
        result = UserList.objects.filter(user=self.context.get('request').user,movie=obj)
        if result:
            return result[0].watched
        return False
```

This is the view code

```
class MovieSearchView(generics.ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('title',)
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For genres: You can use `values_list`.

Try this in your get_genres:

```
def get_genres(self, obj):
    return MovieGenre.objects.filter(movie=obj).values_list('genre', flat=True)
```

I assume that the `genre` is the field name of MovieGenre model.

And for the movie key - as it is currently in your question - there should not be any movie key. Your serializer does not have it. So i cant see why you have the output unless there is something else you did not include.

The serializer should producer list of serialized movie objects.

Try to remove `StandardResultsSetPagination` and see if it is correct.